# Setting up MongoDB with Kubernetes on Google Cloud

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to deploy MongoDB on Google Cloud using Kubernetes. However, I'm having some difficulties. It says:

> error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 29: found character that cannot start any token

However, on line 29 there's only a space indenting the line, as shown below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongo-pv-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    role: mongo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--replSet"
            - rs0
            - "--smallfiles"
            - "--noprealloc"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
          volumes:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: mongo-pv-claim
```

Could somebody point me to where I'm doing something wrong, or more resources on the matter? I've only recently started using Kubernetes, so would appreciate any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had two issues with formatting your yaml file:

1. `volumes` should be on the same level as `containers`.
2. `persistentVolumeClaim` should be under `- name: mongo-persistent-storage` in `volumes` statement.

Correct yaml file is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongo-pv-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    role: mongo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--replSet"
            - rs0
            - "--smallfiles"
            - "--noprealloc"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: mongo-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mongo-pv-claim
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That seems to have solved the problem.